# Spring Boot REST: @DeleteMapping that consuming form_urlencoded not work as expect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot 1.4.0, Consider below code in a `@RestController`, what I expect is, the server side will receive a http body with form_urlencoded content type, but unfortunately it demands me a `query` parameter type with `email` and `token`. What's the problem here and how to fix?

```
@DeleteMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void removeAdmin(@RequestParam(value = "email") String email, @RequestParam(value = "token") String token) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: The web container seems to have thrown away the body of DELETE. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2074380/1986241

Answer (score 3):

`@DeleteMapping` is only a convenience extension the provides  `@RequestMapping(method=DELETE)`  It will not handle request paramters.   You will still have to map those in the controllers method signature if you need the data to perform the work.

Since you want a body,  You could create an object and mark it as @RequestBody:

```
public class DeleteBody {
    public String email;
    public String token;
}

public void removeAdmin(@RequestBody DeleteBody deleteBody) {
...
}
```

Comment: But why @PostMapping does the trick for me and works just as I expect?